# Shading Area in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

Here is the code that I am using

```
x = 0.001:0.05:4*pi;
f = cos(x)+10*sin(x)./x;
hold on
plot(x,f,'r')
axis([0,4*pi,-3,3])
grid on

bid = x(abs(f)>1);
ha = area([0 bid], [10 10]);
hold off
```

This code looks at the energy band gaps allowed. I want to find values for when absolute value of f(x) > 1 and then shade these regions in because these are the not allowed states. So I found the x values for where 
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I get an error running your code: `Error using area (line 35)
X must be same length as Y.` - MATLAB R2015a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do the job?

```
x = 0.001:0.05:4*pi;
f = cos(x)+10*sin(x)./x;
figure();
hold on
plot(x,f,'r')
axis([0,4*pi,-3,3])
grid on

idx = abs(f) > 1;
ys = zeros(size(x));
ys(idx)=f(idx);
ha = area(x, ys);
```